# this.user is undefined when fetch data from app.component in angular -oidc-client

Tags: angular, openid-connect, oidc-client-js, oidc-client

I am using `oidc-client.js` in my `angular` project.

Right now users could log-in and log out and it works fine. the only problem is that when I want to call a service in app.component, in the interceptor the user is not authenticated.

auth.service is :

```
    Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService extends BaseService {


  private _authNavStatusSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  authNavStatus$ = this._authNavStatusSource.asObservable();

  private manager = new UserManager(getClientSettings());
  private user: User | null;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    super();   
    this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
      this._authNavStatusSource.next(this.isAuthenticated());
    });
  }

  login() {
    return this.manager.signinRedirect();
  }

  async completeAuthentication() {
    this.user = await this.manager.signinRedirectCallback();
    this._authNavStatusSource.next(this.isAuthenticated());
  }


  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return this.user != null && !this.user.expired;
  }

  get authorizationHeaderValue(): string {
    return `${this.user.token_type} ${this.user.access_token}`;
  }

  async signout() {
    await this.manager.signoutRedirect();
  }
}

export function getClientSettings(): UserManagerSettings {
  return {
    authority:environment.authApiURI,
    client_id: 'medilloxdashboard',
    redirect_uri: environment.redirect_uri,
    post_logout_redirect_uri: environment.postLogoutRedirectUri,
    response_type: "id_token token",
    scope: "openid spa profile",
    filterProtocolClaims: true,
    loadUserInfo: true,
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    silent_redirect_uri:environment.silentRedirectUri,
    userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: localStorage })
  };
}
```

and I wrote an interceptor to add token to all requests like this :

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private authorizationHeader = "Authorization";

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router) { }
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
      headers: request.headers.set(this.authorizationHeader, this.authService.authorizationHeaderValue)
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }

}
```

`AuthService` and `AuthInterceptor` are registered in `Core nodule`.

In the `App.Compoentn` I call a service like this which call a `REST api`

```
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'myapp';
  version: string;

     constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private dashboardService: DashboardService) {
        this.version = environment.version;
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dashboardService.getDashboards().subscribe();
      }
    }
```

when this call happen, I get `getDashboards failed: this.user is undefined`
but I call exactly this service in another components and it works fine.

> components which call this service and get the result are in their
> modules.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an `Initializer` like this

```
import { AuthService } from "./auth-service";
export function AuthInitializer(auth: AuthService) { return () => auth.isAuthenticated() };
```

and registered like this in `core.module`

```
providers: [

{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: AuthInitializer,
  deps: [AuthService],
  multi: true
}]
```

this is working perefectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make your call inside and `ngAfterViewCheck` instead of `ngOnInit` because services at this moment aren't initiated yet. Be careful that would be executed infinitely. You can keep make the call, while the user is undefined.

Comment: In `ngAfterViewChecked` it is ok but this code run whenever I click on each butttons. Is there a better way?

Comment: my answer below (new stack answer)

Answer (score 1):

To answer to your question **@osman Rahimi** "In ngAfterViewChecked it is ok but this code run whenever I click on each butttons. Is there a better way?"

The answer :

```
  data: any;
  ngAfterViewChecked (): void {
    if(this.data === null || this.data === undefined) {
      this.dashboardService.getDashboards().subscribe(data => this.data = data);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I posted a new answer, please check in order to see is it ok or no